# $ 10^{-9}[2\times10^6 + 3^{1000}] $

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

$$ 10^{-9}[2\times10^6 + 3^{1000}] $$

I'm stuck on solving this. I wasn't able to put this into my calculator since the number is too big for it to calculate.

So far I've done this:

$$ 2\times10^{-3} + 3^{1000}\times10^{-9} $$
log the equation
$$ \log[2\times10^{-3} + 3^{1000}\times10^{-9}] $$
$$ \log(2\times10^{-3}) + \log(3^{1000}\times10^{-9}) $$
$$ (\log\,2 + log\,10^{-3}) + (\log\,3^{1000} + \log \, 10^{-9}) $$
$$ (\log \, 2 - 3) + (1000 \times \log \, 3 - 9) $$

How do I get rid of the log afterwards?

Comment: There's a mistake in your second line.  $\log(a + b) \neq \log a + \log b$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like to do with your factored number. What you begin with is nearly as simple as it gets, except possibly for distributing the $10^{-9}$, which you've done.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. How do I upvote your rep?

Comment: I'm trying to get how many seconds gets outputted from the equation. It wouldn't be right if I said 1000 x log3 seconds.

Comment: Oh sorry. [Here it is now](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+10%5E%28%E2%88%929%29*%5B2%C3%9710%5E6%2B3%5E1000%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

distribute the sum as $ 10^{-9}[2\times10^6] + 10^{-9}\times 3^{1000} $, and write $3^{1000}$ as $10^{{1000}\log_{10}{3}}$

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what form you want the answer in.  You can type it into [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E%28-9%29%2a%282%2a10%5E6%2b3%5E1000%29) and get a number with $469$ digits, but that is not very useful.  One of the big points of the exercise was to see that the $2 \times 10^6$ is **completely negligible** compared to $3^{1000}$, so ignore it.  In fact, it is smaller by a factor of more than $10^{470}$.  Then you can write it as $10^{1000 \log_{10}3-9}\approx 10^{468}$ and I would leave it like that.